# event in each doesn't work

Tags: jquery

This code doesn't work

```
jQuery.each(["Alloggio","Macchina","Aereo","Treno"], function(){         
        t = this;
        $("#ChkPrenotazione" + t + "Default").change(function(){            
            $(".Chk" + t).val($(this).val());        
        });
    });
```

I want that t inner on change event is equal to "Alloggio" or "Macchina" or "Aereo" or "Treno"

How can i fix it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the `t` locally. This can be done with a closure:

```
jQuery.each(["Alloggio","Macchina","Aereo","Treno"], function(){         
    $("#ChkPrenotazione" + this + "Default").change((function(t){
        return function() {
            $(".Chk" + t).val($(this).val());
        };
    })(this));
});
```

Here we use the function `function(t) { … }` to return a function with our corresponding `this`. This is done by calling that function with `this` as the parameter for `t`.